# cython search for value in matrix

Tags: matrix, cython

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

x = np.array(
[[1,1,0.293729457],
[1,2,0.414213648],
[1,3,0.420339974],
[2,1,0.394448377],
[2,2,0.550755237],
[2,3,0.876993966]
]
)
```

i have a 6x3 matrix. column 1 and 2 are the indexes, and column 3 is the value.
question is how do i quickly look up value given col 1 and 2? eg, given col 1 = 1 and col 2 = 3, i want return 0.420339974.

i tried loop to find for each column but it would be slow if i have a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Jason,

### Short answer

You can use `np.where` as follows and `np.logical_and` as follows:

```
In [10]: x[np.where(np.logical_and(x[:,0]==1,x[:,1]==3))][0][2]
Out[10]: 0.42033997400000001
```

### Long answer

To explicate a bit, `x[:,0]==1` and `x[:,1]==3` return arrays of booleans, equal in size to the length of `x`. First let's define two variables to store your conditions:

```
In [12]: a = x[:,0]==1
In [13]: b = x[:,1]==3
```

You cannot use Python's builtin `and`, as in `a and b` because it will first attempt to convert its arguments to booleans:

```
In [15]: a and b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cb10dcaa1a1e> in <module>()
----> 1 a and b

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Instead, use numpy's `logical_and` which returns an array of element-wise ands. Then, the numpy `where` function returns the indices where its argument are true. The output of `where` is a tuple, technically, whose first element is an array of indices where the `logical_and` evaluated true:

```
In [16]: np.logical_and(a,b)
Out[16]: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [17]: np.where(np.logical_and(a,b))
Out[17]: (array([2]),)
```

`where`, called with a single array as an argument, is equivalent to numpy's `nonzero`:

```
In [18]: np.nonzero(np.logical_and(a,b))
Out[18]: (array([2]),)
```

Finally, it looks like your data could be more logically organized (and more compact, for that matter) as a 2D matrix of values only:

```
In [25]: M = 2
In [26]: N = 3
In [27]: data = np.zeros((M,N))
In [28]: for datum in x:
data[datum[0]-1,datum[1]-1]=datum[2]

In [30]: data
Out[30]: 
array([[ 0.29372946,  0.41421365,  0.42033997],
       [ 0.39444838,  0.55075524,  0.87699397]])
```

Then your lookup is trivial, notwithstanding the switch from 1-based indexing to 0-based indexing:

```
In [31]: data[0][2]
Out[31]: 0.42033997400000001
```

-Ravi

Comment: Thank for the comments. After i dig into the libcpp, i used the following from libcpp.map cimport map

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

x = np.array(
[[1,1,0.293729457],
[1,2,0.414213648],
[1,3,0.420339974],
[2,1,0.394448377],
[2,2,0.550755237],
[2,3,0.876993966]
]
)


def F(int c1, int c2, x = x):
    cdef map[int, map[int, float]] my_map
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(x.shape[0]):
        my_map[x[i,0]][x[i,1]] = x[i,2]

    return my_map[c1][c2]

print F(1,2)
it works similar to your 2d matrix look up.

Answer (score 1):

After i dig into the libcpp, i used the following

```
from libcpp.map cimport map

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

x = np.array(
[[1,1,0.293729457],
[1,2,0.414213648],
[1,3,0.420339974],
[2,1,0.394448377],
[2,2,0.550755237],
[2,3,0.876993966]
]
)


def F(int c1, int c2, x = x):
    cdef map[int, map[int, float]] my_map
    cdef int i
    for i in xrange(x.shape[0]):
        my_map[x[i,0]][x[i,1]] = x[i,2]

    return my_map[c1][c2]

print F(1,2)
```

it works similar to your 2d matrix look up.

Answer (score 0):

It  really depends on your use case, and the size of the dataset. If you need to query your dataset just once, I'm afraid, you won't avoid just looping over all the rows, in the end.

However, if you can afford some computational overhead to pre-process your dataset in order to quickly perform multiple subsequent queries, several approaches come to mind.

- the simplest would probably to simply copy the data to a 2D array, where the indexes (`i, j`) correspond directly to the row in the original array with those indexes. This could even be done with a simple `ndarray.reshape` if your original data is sorted and homogeneous.
- For more [fancy and general apporaches](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html#indexed-searches), you could have a look how PyTables does efficient queries for large datasets. In general terms, you create an index of the necessary columns so that queries are performed more efficiently, the same way it is done with relational databases.

There are numerous things that could be attempted. First, though, you need to decide on the algorithm to use, and only later see if Cython would be worth using to optimize it.